# Is log4javascript vulnerable to Apache Log4j (Java logging library) remote code execution CVE-2021-44228?

Tags: security, log4j, log4javascript

Typescript is using log4javascript, is it the same as log4j?
If yes, how can we keep our application secure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Log4JS npm package vulnerable to CVE-2021-44228 Log4J vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336103/is-log4js-npm-package-vulnerable-to-cve-2021-44228-log4j-vulnerability)

Comment: Are Log4JS and Log4Javascript the same?

Comment: No, but the Log4j bug can not be implemented in any other non-JVM language. Only Java has JNDI lookups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4javascript is a JavaScript dependency (as the name already says). log4j is a Java dependency and only this is vulnerable. log4javascript is not vulnerable to CVE-2021-44228 and a JavaScript program cannot depend on the Java library log4j. The languages are not compatible.